# Select random rows in mysql and limit within each group

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble reducing 12 mysql queries into one call.  I need to group the results by `product_type_id` in a random order and then limit each group by 7:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_id=1 AND deleted='n' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7;
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_id=2 AND deleted='n' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7;
...
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_id=12 AND deleted='n' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7;
```

There are 12 total queries currently for each product_type_id (1,2,3,...12).  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You want 84 results, 7 random results from each product type?

Comment: can you not use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 3):

So you need 7 random records for each product type (7 * 12 records). At first sight you're just looking for a union.

```
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_id=1 AND deleted='n' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_id=2 AND deleted='n' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7)
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_id=12 AND deleted='n' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7)
```

If you need to order the whole resultset then you can use an `ORDER BY` clause after the whole `UNION`.

Comment: Just tested this and it works perfect.  Quick answer too.  Thanks.